# I have this error: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, nullpointerexception, treeset

I need to send information(ip+nombre+ventas)from a client to a server through a socket, but it doesn't work. I have to put this information in a TREE SET collection. I have a project with two java class, one is this and the other one is ObjServidor, where the functions as getventas, getip, getnombre are implemented. Could you help me?

```
public class HILO extends Thread {

    private final Socket s;
    private final TreeSet<ObjServidor> O;

    HILO(Socket s, TreeSet<ObjServidor> O) {

        this.s = s;
        this.O = O;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            ObjectInputStream pw = new ObjectInputStream(
                    s.getInputStream());

            // RECORRER LA COLECCION EXTRAYENDO NOMBRE Y VENTAS Y CON EL SOCKET LA IP
            // CREO UNA INSTANCIA PARA CADA ELEMENTO QUE RECIBIMOS NEW
            // HACEMOS EL PUT TODO MEDIANTE UN ITERADOR
            // SACAMOS EL CONTENIDO DE LA COLECCION
            String ip, nombre;
            int ventas;

            TreeSet<ObjServidor> servidorHS = new TreeSet<ObjServidor>();


           Iterator<ObjServidor> it = O.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                ObjServidor aux2;
                aux2 = it.next();
                nombre = aux2.getNombre();
                ventas = aux2.getVentas();
                ip = s.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
            }
            ObjServidor aux []=new ObjServidor[10];
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {   
              aux[i]= new ObjServidor();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<aux.length;i++)
            {
                servidorHS.add(aux[i]);

            }

            it = servidorHS.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(it.next());
            }
            System.out.println("Peticiones recibidas ");
            pw.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: post the error stack trace

Comment: Your code does nothing meaningful, it does not even read the object stream. Instead you create an empty treeset, trying to iterate over it. You determine the sender's IP not just once per socket, but multiple times. You use meaningless class names such as `ObjServidor` (which objects?) and `HILO` (Spanish word for thread?) and bad variable names (`s`, `O`), obfuscating the code. You create fixed-length arrays as if you knew the size of each tree set in advance. You use old-fashioned iterators instead of modern for loops. I could go on and on. And yes, I agree the stack trace is missing.